# Batch reachs the limit of 50000 records

Tags: batch, governorlimits, aggregateresult

I trigger via flow the class below to get the sum of BWS_val__c if the status not contains 'Pol', but if the status contains pol the class execute a batch class. I thought that the batch class can process more than 50000 records, but that's not the case :-(

Is there a way to process more than 50000 records?

```
public class get_SumCC {  
    @InvocableMethod(label='Status' description='') 
    public static List<decimal> getStatusValue(List<String> Status) {       
        list<decimal> Amounts = new list<decimal>();
        string checkstatus = Status.get(0);
        IF(checkstatus.contains('Pol')) {           
            Id bc = Database.executeBatch(new get_SumCC_Batch(), 200);
        } ELSE {            
            AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT sum(BWS_val__c) FROM CustomCC__c WHERE Status__c = :Status.get(0)]; 
            for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
                Amounts.add(decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'))));
            } 
        }       
        return Amounts;
    }        
}
```

**BATCH CLASS**

```
public class get_SumCC_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    
    public String query = 'SELECT Id FROM CustomCC__c';
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<CustomCC__c> records){
        List<AggregateResult> groupedResults = [SELECT sum(BWS_val__c) BWS FROM CustomCC__c WHERE Status__c Like 'Pol%'];       
        for (AggregateResult ar: groupedResults) {
            CustomCC_trend__c ccct2            = new CustomCC_trend__c ();
            ccct2.BWS_val__c                   = (Decimal) ar.get('BWS');
            ccct2.date__c                      = System.today();
            ccct2.Status__c                    = 'Pol';
            insert ccct2;
        }
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    }    
}
```

Comment: Each call to `execute` is a transaction where governor limits apply. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm explains this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit says:

The `start` method can return upto 50 million records.

And the execute method can then process those in chucks of 200 by default or max till 2000.

In this method `List<AggregateResult> groupedResults = [SELECT sum(BWS_val__c) BWS FROM CustomCC__c WHERE Status__c Like 'Pol%'];`

I dont see you have added the `id` check.

It should be like this.

`List<AggregateResult> groupedResults = [SELECT sum(BWS_val__c) BWS FROM CustomCC__c WHERE Status__c Like 'Pol%' AND Id = :records];`

Also remove your DML `insert` keyword from loop and do it outside of loop.

Comment: I prefer to test ID matching first in SOQL (it is more selective and I have seen SOQL actually perform better by switching order of terms in the `WHERE` clause) and prefer to use `IN` when comparing against collections (since it becomes more obvious to the reader, even though what you have here is legal).

Comment: It would also be better to enumerate the status values than use `LIKE` matching, from a performance perspective. (This comment to the OP, not Nagendra)